# what is the 101 error code mean in in-app-billing v3 library?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am using in app billing v3 library, it is always get error
and error code is `101`

What does this error code mean?

some details:
 I am a developer working from Palestine and working on an app uploadded on Indian google play account

I created activity that included three buttons to purchase remove Ads

-the first button to subscribe one month

-the second to subscribe one year

-the third to purchase lifetime

I used this library 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'

I created product in google play console and its name PRODUCT_ID
this product will purchased when user click on button lifeTime

and I created two subscriptions

-the first's name is SUBSCRIPTION_MONTH_ID
and will be purchased when the user click on oneMonth button

-the second's name is SUBSCRIPTION_YEAR_ID
and will be purchased when the user click on oneYear button

this the code that I used

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.BillingProcessor;
import com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.TransactionDetails;

public class InAppBilling extends AppCompatActivity{
BillingProcessor bp;

private static final String PRODUCT_ID = "****";
private static final String SUBSCRIPTION_MONTH_ID = "***";
private static final String SUBSCRIPTION_YEAR_ID = "***";
private static final String LICENSE_KEY = "*****";
private static final String MERCHANT_ID = "**";

Button oneMonth, oneYear, lifeTime;
int flag;
String android_id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_in_app_purchase);

    flag = 0;

    android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        toolbar.setTitle("Remove Ads");
    }

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    if(!BillingProcessor.isIabServiceAvailable(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "In-app billing service is unavailable, please upgrade Android Market/Play to version >= 3.9.16", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    bp = new BillingProcessor(this, LICENSE_KEY, MERCHANT_ID, new BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
            Toast.makeText(InAppBilling.this, "successfully purchased, restart the app please", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {
            Toast.makeText(InAppBilling.this, "Error Billing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("nourbilling", "onBillingError: errorCode: "+errorCode+" error: "+error);
        }
        @Override
        public void onBillingInitialized() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
            for(String sku : bp.listOwnedProducts())
                Log.d("nourbilling", "Owned Managed Product: " + sku);
            for(String sku : bp.listOwnedSubscriptions())
                Log.d("nourbilling", "Owned Subscription: " + sku);
        }
    });

    oneMonth = findViewById(R.id.oneMonth);
    oneYear = findViewById(R.id.oneYear);
    lifeTime = findViewById(R.id.lifetime);

    final Activity activity = this;

    oneMonth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flag = 1;
            createDialog(savedInstanceState, activity).show();
        }
    });

    oneYear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flag = 2;
            createDialog(savedInstanceState, activity).show();
        }
    });

    lifeTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flag = 3;
            createDialog(savedInstanceState, activity).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (bp != null)
        bp.release();
    super.onDestroy();
}

public Dialog createDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState, final Activity activity) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("are you sure to remove ads by billing?")
            .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    if (flag == 1) {
                        bp.subscribe(activity, SUBSCRIPTION_MONTH_ID);
                    } else if (flag == 2) {
                        bp.subscribe(activity, SUBSCRIPTION_YEAR_ID);
                    } else if (flag == 3) {
                        bp.purchase(activity, PRODUCT_ID);
                    }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            });
    return builder.create();

}
}
```

can you help me, please?

Comment: Edit the question and add more details to it. Which function are you calling? Please go through how to ask a question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @KishanVaishnav
I have edited the question, can you help me, please?

Comment: I looked at your code and fount 101 at https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/anjlab/android/iab/v3/BillingProcessor.java which is Constants.BILLING_ERROR_FAILED_TO_INITIALIZE_PURCHASE. This error comes when getBuyIntent() method of the In-app Billing Version 3.

It basically means it cannot initialize the purchase flow.

Why are you not using Google Play Billing Library BTW?

Comment: is there a solution for this problem? @KishanVaishnav
Do you have any tututorial for Play Billing Library?

Comment: You can read official documentation from https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview and sample app TrivialDrive

Comment: InApp purchase is no joke. I had to read for at least one week to understand how it worked. Even though I just had to implement the backend Web API. So go and download the sample app, debug, play with it and then you can plan to implement it.

Comment: ok, thank you very much @KishanVaishnav . I will download this sample